# Should we discourage big list-style answers to questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

Certain questions, such as [What are some options for syntax for async/await?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-are-some-options-for-syntax-for-async-await), have [answers](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/114/9) which are essentially big lists of possible answers to the question. Should we discourage these types of answers?

Answer (score 5):

No, on the contrary, **all answers should actually strive to answer the question**. If the answer to a question is “use method A in circumstances X and method B otherwise”, then the whole explanation belongs in a single answer. It doesn't make sense to split A-if-X and B-if-not-X into separate answers. A and B shouldn't to be rated against each other through voting. Voting is supposed to rate the quality of the answer, i.e. the breadth of what it explains and the clarity of the explanation, not the popularity of the solution.

If you find a question that seems to call for answers ranked by popularity, [close the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic). Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a poll site.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

They don't fully leverage the power of Stack Exchange's voting system, and take away the opportunity for other users to post answers and gain reputation.

Comment: [No, quite the contrary](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/190). You're trying to construct a site for polls, not a site for answers, and with this attitude the site won't survive.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nuance- particularly to questions that explicitly or subtly solicit lists, and I've been trying to get this across in my various posts here on meta. Out of a bit of feeling of exhaust at having posted on this topic three times within the span of two days, I defer to what I've already written in those posts:

- https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/147/251
- [Let's please do better at objectivity when doing Q&A about design choices](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/161/251)
- https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/251

Answer (score 0):

> Not necessarily

If everything in the list is useful that allow it. Only if you are listng nonsense is it a problem.

Comment: Self-reference is not required.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score -3):

I am strongly against these questions.

Comment: I don't think this belongs in this thread, this is its own question on meta.

Comment: Any particular reason? Please state it